# What are the localized versions and where can I find them?

Tags: support, internationalization

Today I came across a localized Stack Overflow site, ja.stackoverflow.com, through a user's profile. It is the Japanese version of this site. Are there other languages of the site? Where can I find them?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

They are listed in the full list of [all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions) in the network.

Currently we have Stack Overflow sites in:

- [Portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com)
- [Japanese](http://ja.stackoverflow.com)
- [Russian](http://ru.stackoverflow.com)
- [Spanish](http://es.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Oh, I see, so each site is an independent site, they are not a translation site?

Comment: No, they are not. They are fully localized, separate websites.

Comment: And the [Turkish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish) one looks like it's launching soon.

Comment: Really hope to see SO in Chinese one day. The sooner, the better :).

Comment: @YuHao, I disagree with you. Let's say a Chinese SO exists and I (non-Chinese speaker) have a question. If it is not already asked/answered on English SO but only on the Chinese (independent) variant, I will not be able to find the question/answer.

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra - however unlikely that may be, it *doesn't* take away anything from the English version. There is a logical fallacy in believing that if an answer exists on (a possible future) Chinese SO and not on the English one, if the Chinese one didn't exist the answer would somehow exist on the English one.

Comment: @Oded, that is true. I'm very interested in what happens when the localized versions of large languages (Spanish, (possible) Chinese) are more actively used: would it mean that English SO would be used less? Will they become more active or will a 'one-language-SO' appear to be more useful? Interesting questions. (I'm a linguist, programmer and data scientist. This is a very interesting research area.)

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra - we have anecdotal info from the Portuguese SO - people who are active on both sites cross-pollinate them. Both communities benefit. The point of the "language" sites is to enable users who are either uncomfortable or unfamiliar with English. They don't contribute to the English site anyway, so giving them a venue is only a net positive.

Comment: @Oded, I see: I didn't think of the language-specific SOs as being complementary to the English one. Good to hear these SOs are of benefit.

Comment: Note that if you want to find something on SO, using Google works better than using the site-specific search anyway, so it wouldn't really matter what sub-site a question was on - Google can find it anyway.

Comment: @YuHao: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​[But that's impossible I think.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158892/305595)

Comment: @KevinGuan [The question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158891/when-will-stackoverflow-subsite-support-chinese) you linked was posted over 3.5 years ago.  Now there are already 4  fully localized SO site. I don't think that answer reflects today's policy.

Comment: @YuHao: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Hmm...maybe a bounty then. I'll be happy if we can have a Chinese Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MrLister: To be fair, Microsoft Bob works better than site-specific search

Comment: @Oded "...it doesn't take away anything from the English version." In the short-term, no. But in the long term run, we all would benefit by being able to use the same community and the same language. English is the de-facto global standard today, and offering localized communities will quite obviously reduce the need for non-native English speakers like myself to invest in access in and contribution to the greater community. Fight segregation by reducing segregation, not by making segregation more convenient.

Comment: @Alex - I disagree. There are a lot of people who simply *cannot* participate and use the same language as you do. "English is the de-facto global standard today" - tell that to publishers who publish programming books that are not in English - why would they do that? This is about enabling these people - giving them a place to participate in instead of simply not participating.

Comment: @Oded I'm not saying that there isn't people who are not fluent enough in English and that there isn't a market for it. But I want a healthy global community where everyone is able to communicate with each other and where we together can reap the effects described by Metcalfe's law. In order to achieve that, we must reduce segregation by enabling people **and making them join the global community**. Groups that can not communicate with each other are well isolated from each other. English is an obvious part of programming, even in non-English countries like my own.

Comment: Our focus should be to nudge these people, where the dependency on English already is quite obvious, over to the global community, not to make them more comfortable in their own separate communities.

Comment: @Alex - I am not a native speaker and my English had been so bad. I could understand but hadn't been able to build fluent sentences. I'm still far away from being perfect, however, SO is the reason I've learned to speak English much better compared to former. Here are people with really little knowledge in English, but they have the guts to write. I've helped to improve some questions to become more understandable. Editing is a nice feature. The community will help. I'm afraid I could become too lazy to practice English any longer when a German site of SO started.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Thank you, that is precisely my point. It was the same for me, it's a long path to learn and being comfortable in a new language, but it really is worth getting access to the community where the knowledge and experience is so much better. If I wanted to empower programmers globally, I'd place my focus on 1. Helping and motivating people to learn English to be able to access and contribute to the global community and 2. Figure out how we can integrate with the rapidly maturing Chinese community, which population-wide already is bigger that the English-speaking.

Comment: I think both you and Quasimodo are missing the point - our sites are for helping developers with their day-to-day programming, not to help them with English.

Comment: @Oded I though the point here was about empowering programmers and to build a thriving community, not to simply solve day-to-day issues? Then we are talking about different things.

Comment: We are building a corpus of great questions and answers, and empowering developers. Forcing people who are not comfortable in English to use it is not empowering.

Comment: @Oded Just to be clear, I have no special interest in the English language per se, it just so happen to be the language of most accessible and mature community today. If the Chinese don't give a crap about us and prove to supersede this community, sign me up for mandarin lessons.

I the end of the day, this domain is communication. You want to spread knowledge and empower developers. Being able to connect and communicate with others is pivotal, and making segregation more convenient is not a good long-term strategy.

Comment: @Alex - I would prefer builtin translation tools with patterns of common programming related phrases over spreading into language specific platforms.

Comment: @Alex and Quasimodo - while I agree that in the long run, the community would be united by settling on one language, we need to understand that people are extremely touchy when anyone suggests something that could be perceived as "monolingualism", "cultural imperialism", "extremism", "hating diversity and inclusion" etc. I was [**roasted**](http://bit.ly/twittersphere-for-translation) for [asking folks in an OSS project to also consider the indirect and long-term cost of translating documentation](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/website/issues/94#issuecomment-447616587).