# Translating posts in edits

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, english

I was going through the suggested edit review queue and came across [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12595552) which translates the post to English.

I've skipped it because I have no way of validating the edit (I don't understand the language the post was originally written in). What is the go-to response for this kind of thing? Sure, some reviewers will be able to verify the validity of the edit, but should I have rejected it for a reason, if so, which reason? Should I have flagged it for closure independently of the review?

Comment: Note that now in 2019, ["The mods officially endorse translating posts into English. But with the caveat"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/297680/14) that can be read in the updated version of [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/7795130). As such, this question's base assumption and the guidelines these answers are working off of are obsolete.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would reject the edit and vote to close the question. I know the editor means well, but translating questions from other languages into English is not what editors should be doing. The original author of that question is highly unlikely to be helped by answers written in English if they posted their question in any other language. (And if they failed to notice that every other post on the site is also in English.) If they need help with translation, they should have a friend or colleague help them before they post.

Comment: Makes sense. What reject reason would be most appropriate for it? Changing author intent / does it really matter?

Comment: @Joe I would write a custom off-topic reason letting the OP know that this is an English-only site.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, reject the edit and close the question. In addition, leave a comment for the OP that they should ask questions in [English only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) - for questions in Spanish we have [another Stack Overflow site](http://es.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323148