# False Positive Spanish Language Detection when Asking Question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, asking-questions, title, languages

When trying to formulate a title for a question about the Swift language REPL, I noticed that Stack Overflow thought I was trying to ask a question in Spanish.

[image: Ask Question]

Is this intended for this title?

After changing the title to a more grammatically correct title (Unload an Imported Module in the Swift REPL), the message closed itself.

Comment: I would say: write a longer and descriptive title....

Comment: I think it is picking up on "Un".

Comment: It has to be the "un."  The longer title "Swift REPL - Un-import previously imported and included module" still triggers the message.

Comment: Cramming tags in your title, I see.

Comment: @Will inb4 14k user should know better

Comment: A 14k user should oh damnit

Comment: Did it again - here on meta, you, in this questions's title.

Comment: Titles should be sentences. You are adding tag-like contents add the beginning. I'm referring to the "Swift REPL - " or "Question Title -" part of your titles.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is a temporary experiment to estimate the number of Spanish-language posts being asked on Stack Overflow, in order to determine whether it's worth spending the time to build [a proper classifier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323148/should-i-encourage-people-to-use-the-localized-versions-of-so/323188#323188) for these.

So right now, it's triggered by a bunch of sketchy words like "em" and "un". We'll turn it off in a month or two and analyze the results to determine effectiveness.

Full list of trigger words:

- EM|UM|UMA|NÃO|AO|DADOS|ERRO|NA|FAZER|É|BANCO|OU|ARQUIVO|CRIAR (Portuguese)
- UN|CON|CÓMO|UNA|EL|AL|PUEDO|DATOS|COMO|DESDE|HACER|QUÉ|DEL|MI (Spanish)

Full list of trigger characters:

- àáâãéêíóôõúü (Portuguese)
- áéíóúüñ¿¡ (Spanish)

Preemptive: yes, I could be a *lot* more clever here and reduce false positives considerably... But this would also result in more false negatives, and since the whole point is to get an estimate of how many folks are asking these it's easier to sort out false positives than false negatives. I do apologize for any confusion that results.

Comment: `em` is hardly sketchy...since it's a CSS length.

Comment: I know, @Paulie_D - IIRC, Em and El are some sort of thing in R also. That's what makes 'em sketchy triggers here, tons of false-positives.

Comment: So, ç do not trigger Portuguese also?

Comment: It doesn't, @VictorStafusa

Comment: regarding your spanish words triggers. Be aware some of those without accent are also valid `COMO|QUE|ÉL` also as a spanish writer I can tell you web users are lazy regarding accents unless word autocorrect fix it for them.

Comment: Why not just do an analysis on questions as they're asked before being edited into English, and include questions that were deleted (which'd include those deleted for being in the wrong language)?

Comment: Won't Spanish characters also trigger on German, French, Italian and a bunch of other languages that use accents and umlauts?

Comment: Lowish-lift tweak: maybe suppressing that if the title contains any of list of common English words that are not in those other languages (e.g., 'the', 'of', etc. but not 'a'). Andrew's suggestion to avoid showing UI at this stage seems reasonable, too.

Comment: Separately, `navigator.languages ? navigator.languages[0] : navigator.language` [tells you browser locale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673905/best-way-to-determine-users-locale-within-browser) (which has its limits, of course).

Comment: @Shog9 Cant you run these through google translate and see what "suggested language" is?

Comment: Yeah, that has a lot of problems all on its own, @twotwotwo... But most importantly, it doesn't tell us the nature of what the browser's operator is *writing*.

Comment: Yes, craploads of false-positives, @Sulthan. See last paragraph.

Comment: Yes, lots of better ways to do this, @FooBar. Just not lots of better ways of doing this *today*. See last paragraph.

Comment: Any plan on doing this in [es.so]? We currently have a 6% of closed questions due to the specific reason "it is not in Spanish", which 99% of cases means "it is in English". You can find [more details here](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2043/podr%C3%ADamos-tener-un-peque%C3%B1o-detector-de-publicaciones-en-ingl%C3%A9s-que-notificara-a?noredirect=1#comment10257_2043) .. the discussion in Spanish, but links are in English. It looks like the UX is kind of... complicated, at least.

Comment: This is a fairly terrible heuristic, @fedorqui; I don't know if we could readily identify English questions on ESSO by a few keywords, but if possible it'd take some thorough analysis. An ideal system would attempt to determine if the title (or body...) was grammatical in the target language, but we have no facility for doing so at present.

Comment: @Shog9 I lack the rep (and the knowledge) to browse through deleted questions and do some analysis on the closed questions. In many cases valid Spanish questions contain English sentences (errors from the programming language and things like that), but detecting the language of a post should not be that complicated, [Google offers a service for it](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/detecting-language), for example.

Comment: For the record, I created a question somehow related to this topic: [Let's make the automatic removal of salutations language specific!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305125/209901).

Comment: For the record (again :P), I asked this few days ago → [Do we have statistics on how often people asking in different languages get into a localized version of SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365580/1983854). Do we?