# Do we have statistics on how often people asking in different languages get into a localized version of SO?

Tags: support, asking-questions, statistics, languages

In [False Positive Spanish Language Detection when Asking Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325865/1983854) and [Should I encourage people to use the localized versions of SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323249/1983854) we learned that there is a system in place to detect if a question seems to be in a language where a specific Stack Overflow exists: Spanish, Japanese, Russian and Portuguese.

For example, say I type a title ["cómo hago esto y aquello"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=c%C3%B3mo%20hago%20esto%20y%20aquello) (some random Spanish text). I get this tooltip:

> [image]

The text says:

> - Si quieres preguntar en español, lo puedes hacer aquí: [Stack Overflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?utm_source=soen-es).
> - Este site é para perguntas feitas em inglês. Para fazer perguntas em português, visite [pt.stackoverflow.com](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/?utm_source=soen-pt)

(and again in Spanish, which seems to be a bug)

The link point to `http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?utm_source=soen-es` and `http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/?utm_source=soen-pt`. That is, they direct to the Ask a Question page with a `utm_source` flag with a value of either "soen-es" or "soen-pt".

Do we have statistics on how often are those links clicked?

<sub>The reasoning here is that in Stack Overflow en español we are getting quite a lot of questions written in English and most of OPs mention they were coming from Stack Overflow [in English] and we wonder how often do they notice they got into a Spanish speaking site.</sub>

Comment: ".. we wonder how often do they notice they got into a Spanish speaking site .." How often? Don't you mean how *soon*? (Visiting *los primos* at [SO en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) for the very first time, I can confidently state for me that would be "immediately".)

Comment: @usr2564301 hopefully it would be immediately, but the current amount of questions in English makes me wonder that this is not the case. Note they get directed to https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, which looks quite similar to the analogous in SO.

Comment: Maybe their browser translates the site for them making it look like its an english speaking site.

Comment: @AndréKool I suspect a lot of non-native English speakers indeed view their browser through a translator service, because why else would you enter non-English text on a website where everything and everyone is communicating in English? Fat chance that they don't even notice anymore the bad quality of their native tongue online, as translators aren't perfect and they get used to it. Whether the inverse is true as well (native-English people viewing the web through a translator), I wouldn't know. I have it turned off at least for every odd language; I'll chuck it in one myself if necessary.

Comment: It would be plausible since Google Chrome has an automatic prompt for translation. I assume at that point it's all over for notifying them this is an English-only site. Maybe it's just a case of how to be more obvious but I don't see how you can be

Comment: @L_Church we have an [ongoing debate in Meta SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/83) and we are trying to get such a tooltip that detects English text in questions and says "heeeey this should be in Spanish!".

Comment: @fedorqui Keep in mind the link leads them directly to creating a new question. If they do not pay much attention they will likely think it's just a language version with **translated UI** as multilingual websites are a lot more common than having separate "language communities" each with their own website. So it might only become apparent to them after posting their question in English.

Comment: @SørenD.Ptæus good point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask and https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask have exactly the same UI, same colors, same everything.

Comment: sounds interesting. would like to see that so  we don't get the every-now-and-then foreign user post

Comment: @fedorqui Nope, different logo, no jobs on the spanish one, more space between tag field and post button, no review queue in the menu in spanish version (maybe because i have low rep)

Comment: @AndréKool regarding "*their browser translates the site*", it doesn't correlate to what we're getting as feedback on SOes. Most users claim they simply "didn't notice", but no one has mentioned a translator yet. It seems the differences in UI are not very clear to new users (and yes, the review menu is there for 500+).

Comment: As I've mentioned [on Meta SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3365/127), @fedorqui perhaps it would be a good idea to also take into account users with a Spanish Accept-Language clicking on `/ask?fromen=fsorl` or `/ask?fromen=<id>`, which are linked from every question or from the login page on SO.

Comment: @Mariano agreed it would be also useful to have stats about the two other entrypoints you mention, thanks for the reminder! Let's see if we can get info about this one and then try to get from the others.