# Can we emphasise "English only, please" in How To Ask page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, languages

A few minutes back, I came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38060739/2173917) which is written in a non-English language. (Spanish, I guess?)

I left comments informing the OP about the requirement of using English as the question language, and also posted a link to the "[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" page.

But, while reviewing the page myself, I noticed there's a lack of **emphasis** (*irony*) on using English as the question language. The only mention I found there is

> [....]  If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend to proof-read it for you.

For new participants, this may not convey a clear message. Some *may* think in this way,

> *Oh, I'm not good in English, and I don't have someone readily available now to proof-read either, so let me post the question in XYZ language.*

Can we add a line or two, to put emphasis on the fact that the question MUST be in English, in the first place?

*P.S - To give background for why I ask this, it is to be able to point OPs (who have either missed or misunderstood) to the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and be done with it.*

*P.P.S - This is not a duplicate, but an addendum to [Let's improve the How to Ask page(s)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258251/2173917), if that is a concern.*

Comment: Besides I'm supporting this the _"Excuse my bad english"_, _"I'm not good at english"_, etc. rarely have to do with the real quality of the question, regarding a missing MCVE or other popular misses.

Comment: It certainly won't *hurt* anything to emphasize that this is an English-only site, but I'm skeptical that it will help much either. Someone who comes to a site with millions of pages of English text and posts in Spanish anyway is highly unlikely to ever read the How to Ask page.

Comment: Like Bill says, I wonder how many post are not in English. I haven't seen many in the 5.5 years I'm here. And I've seen people translate them (occasionally).

Comment: @BilltheLizard It can absolutely hurt.  It's hard enough to get people to read the how to ask page as it is.  The more you put in there, the less of it will get read.  Putting information in there that anyone actually reading it wouldn't care about is wasting their time, decreasing the odds of them continuing on to things that would actually help them.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Likely, but then, I don't need to post an additional comment informing them abut the language requirement. The standard "check the [ask] page" will do.

Comment: @JanDoggen It's not a quesiton of how many non-English posts there are, but also how many of the users posting them would have done anything any different if there was **English** text in the help center to the them not to post in English.  My guess is that number is, if not *actually* zero, effectively zero.

Comment: @Servy The message is already there. Nothing needs to be added. Emphasizing it shouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: @SouravGhosh If you can't be bothered to provide a specific informative comment targeted to that question (which I wouldn't blame you for; you're almost certainly wasting your time commenting at all in such a situation) then you're better off not commenting at all, rather than providing a comment so generic as to be useless.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Same argument.  Emphasizing one thing, or expanding on it. means that other things aren't emphasized.  Emphasizing something that is providing zero value to anyone reading it means drawing attention away from information that's *actually* important and that readers would have a shot at actually benefiting from reading.

Comment: @Servy Sorry I did not get you. What is "so generic" about pointing to "how to ask", sir? Instead of duplicating the information already pointed in [ask], what's the problem in linking the page in a comment? If the OP chooses to ignore it, well, we all know the result. :)

Comment: Depending on the exact title, users [should already get a suggestion to post on a localized Stack Overflow site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323148/should-i-encourage-people-to-use-the-localized-versions-of-so/323249#323249) if it exists.

Comment: @JanDoggen I don't have an example / data ready now, but I see couple of them almost everyday, if not more. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh What *isn't* generic about it?  You're saying, "you have a problem, read this page that tries to tell you everything you possibly need to know about how to ask a question to try to figure out what I think you didn't get right about it?"  If you feel that there's a specific problem with the question, namely that it's posted in another language, then say that.  If you can't be bothered to say anything other than, "you did *something* wrong" than just downvote/close vote and don't comment, as your comment is adding no value.

Comment: "Emphasize" and "American English"; FTFY :D

Comment: @hichris123 I didn't realize that answer (to my question, BTW) was updated. Why not go further though? In the help center, emphasize that this is an English-only site, and mention the alternative (es|pt|ja|ru)-only sites that you could use if you don't like English.

Comment: Why didn't you suggest the poster go to http://es.stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: When we have this sorted out, we'll have to do the same for *answerers*, who post foreign-language answers to fully English threads with English askers (often in Arabic, Cyrillic or other non-latin alphabet to make it even more obvious)

Comment: @Kevin Was thinking of doing that, but before I could _come back_ from the ask page, the post was _gone_, anyway. :)

Comment: @Servy hmmm, regarding being _specific_ or _generic_, consider the scenario...me travelling in a crowded bus/train, someone steps onto my toe, and I say "hey buddy, watch your steps", __not__ "Hey, your right foot is resting on top of of the my newly polished leather boot of size 9 which i'm wearing on my left foot thereby causing a pain in my feet which is being carried to my brain through my nervous system and creating a reaction which I can understand, comprehend and react to and thus i'm requesting you to re-place your foot."...I can, but I won't.  [cont.....]

Comment: @Servy [...cont] and in both the cases, my message is clear. Hopefully the other person will correct him/herself. Right? All the time, is it mandatory to pinpoint the issue? sometimes it can be as easy as just a cross-check, in case we missed something either in hurry or due to lack of knowledge. Just a thought. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh How does that analogy hold?  A more applicable example would be a cop telling you that you've broken the law and in response to you asking what law you've broken he hands you a law book and tells you to figure it out.  If you're just pointing people to the help center for *every single problem* then you're providing *no* indication of what they did wrong.  You may as well not comment in the first point.  You don't need to go into minute detail, but you should be summarizing the problem in a sentence, in this case, something like, "Posts on SO need to be in English."

Comment: @Servy Fine, I fully agree with the one liner you suggested, but along with that pointing to [ask] can also be helpful (even if not for _that_ particular post, for future ones) and the presence of the requirement of the language in the [ask] page adds weight to my (or anybody else's) comment, as the ask page is authoritative, while individual comments may not.

Comment: @Servy If I comment asking for English, someone can interpret that I don't understand XYZ language and that's why I'm asking for English, I don;t have a diamond next to my name, after all. _What's the proof I'm taking sense?_ :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh If someone questions whether or not what you're telling them is actually a rule/guidelines, then feel free to link them to a relevant source.  If you want to include a source when providing your original critique, feel free to do so, but the point is that just linking to the help center *while saying nothing at all about what they've done wrong* is a useless comment.

Comment: @Servy `link them to a relevant source.` that is what I was trying to ask, to make it explicit that the language MUST be in English. Otherwise, if you can please notice, for questions with no-research-effort, I (atleast personally) use a format "Please show your research effort till time, please read [ask] page first." so that should suffice, right? we can use likewise in this case also, but the link i'm pointing to should be having the content I was mentioning in my comment, right?

Comment: @Servy ..and apart all that, let me thank you for engaging in a constructive discussion on the topic. Much appreciate, sir. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh If they specifically ask for the source of a guideline/rule that you're informing them that they're violating them, then sure, replying with just a link to said source is fine.  But just linking to something as broad as "how to ask" *alone*, with no statement at all about which of the *many* topics discussed on that page is relevant, simply isn't helpful.

Comment: @Servy how about this one ` "Questions should be in English only, please read [ask] page first" `. Makes sense?

Comment: @SouravGhosh That's fine.

Comment: What about you guys learning some Spanish for a change?? English is a so primitive language and Spanish is the language spoken in most countries in the whole world. Its not easy to learn but hey, once you master it you can say EVERYTHING you got in your mind.

Comment: Yes we *can*... But *shall* we?

Comment: Can't think of a recent case that was so much a solution looking for a problem.

Answer (score 17):

TLDR: No, there's no emphasis needed.

This is the first time I've heard about that problem during the 2.5 years that I've been active on Stack Overflow.

If the OP is not familiar with the site, it's also unlikely that he has read or will read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. If he's not familiar with English, it's even possible that he does not understand.

If something like this happens, we already have the means to deal with it:

- use comments to redirect to https://es.stackoverflow.com/ or https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ (or other language specific clones)
- vote as off-topic with exactly the reason used in this case:

  > This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Regarding

> Emphasizing it shouldn't hurt anything.

I disagree: emphasis draws attention and it's more likely that someone who would use English anyway misses a more important point. As a consequence, we emphasize something else and so on.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your views. However, regarding the `vote as off-topic with exactly the reason used in this case:`.... I'm asking to change the text/wordings to make it clear that the language used should be English only so that the part `...within the scope defined in the help center...` is accurate.

Comment: Right, but a custom message just too much effort for a question which is probably going to be deleted in a minute or two. Plus, a custom comment is not authoritative, as i already mentioned in the comments below the question, kindly check that section, too.

Comment: Not to mention, I did almost the same for the (currently deleted) question under discussion. :)

Comment: Well, then I rolled back to the original text.

Comment: right, and that was the source of my very first comment. :)

Comment: A problem I've seen often is that some new users tend to think that established rules don't exist, and any and all comments are to be seen as other users' personal opinions/preferences. So while commenting and directing is fine and all that, I think an unambiguous statement from an authoritative source (i.e. the help center) would greatly aid in convincing new users that English isn't just some people's preference, but an actual requirement here.

Comment: @ThomasWeller This is precisely what my [answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323329/6083675) intended to help with. I was thinking that it would be best if the comments were in their native tongue.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good point. As it currently stands, it's hard to point a user to this page and say "see, you shouldn't have picked english".

The emphasis doesn't have to be in a distracting way as @thomas_weller points out that this might shift the focus off of other important things. But we can word it a bit better saying explicitly that english is mandatory. If we add that it will not distract much, but make it more clearer.

Don't forget, trying to parse a less-clear sentence (which this is) also costs effort, so making it clearer will distract LESS from the other important stuff!

Answer (score -9):

Rather than asking users to read docs that emphasize that English (or any given language) is required, wouldn't it be simpler for everyone to just run a programmatic scan on the question for English vocabulary, and reject it by default if there's none?  If discretely done, most users might never know such a feature existed.

Such a scan needn't be too intelligent, let alone perfect or complete, just *good enough* to reject most or even just *some* non-English, with no false hits.  Checking grammar would not be necessary, (or desirable) -- a simple scan that could be spoofed by a random list of Basic English word roots would probably be good enough.

(On a similar note, blocks of *Code-sample* might be scanned for obvious coding languages, and automatically add a *tag* for that language.)

For more experienced users, such features could be disabled, either by default or from some config page.

Comment: Hint: most programming languages would pass scan for English vocabulary.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov, It would depend on what's doing the scanning, which was deliberately left vague -- the notional requirement being that the method used would, should, and must be adequate.