# Question title containing "con"

Tags: support, questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39475219/73070) question's asker complained that they were not able to use the word "con" in the title of their question. And, true enough, some popup appears telling me something in Spanish, when I try editing the question (I initially thought it was some kind of limitation regarding new users).

It appears to be an attempt to weed out questions that may be in Spanish and direct them to Stack Overflow in Spanish. But it seems to catch a bit more than intended here.

Comment: I suppose it's good to re-evaluate these things, but the standard answer is "we're ok with a small number of false positives compared to what we're catching."

Comment: Fixed. Zero-width spaces FTW.

Comment: Tried it and saw the popup as well. If that is an attempt to get people to use SOes, that is ridiculous. [Con](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/con) is a proper English word as well.

Comment: Haha, nice one ;)

Comment: They run Windows. They're just very diligent in protecting themselves against this https://what.thedailywtf.com/topic/377/how-to-crash-windows-98-very-very-badly You never know!!!!!!1

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323249/6083675

Comment: Oooh, nice dupe UI.