# Developer Survey inclusion metric: natural language

Tags: discussion, survey

I was looking through the [Demographics section of the 2018 Developer Survey results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018) and noted the under-representation of women and non-white ethnicities. I haven't seen any data about the natural language(s) that developers are comfortable with, and I suspect English is over-represented. Is this data available from other sources?

Since we ask developers quite detailed questions anyway (like [what time they wake up](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018#developer-profile-what-time-do-developers-wake-up)), I thought it might be insightful to also ask what human language(s) they use in their work that they feel they're sufficiently proficient in. To help avoid the English bias, it would be good to notify users in the [localized versions of SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322314/1269037) as well (currently Japanese, Spanish, Russian, and Portuguese).

Can we add this question to next year's Developer Survey? How should it be presented to ensure fair and appropriate responses?

**EDIT**: turns out [this question was proposed for the 2019 survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375907/developer-survey-2019-any-topic-suggestions/375947#375947)

Comment: There was a big discussion on Twitter yesterday including a few Stack people regarding the extent to which English is or is not a de-facto standard in the programming world. This would be valuable data to have.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Some data from https://git.io/top: out of the top 10 contributors, half are likely non-native speakers. All pinned repos of the top 10 contributors are in English. **egoist** is Chinese and **HugoGiraudel** is a diversity advocate, and both publish in English.

Comment: And some data from the [top 100 GitHub repos by # of stars](https://github.com/search?l=&o=desc&q=stars%3A%22%3E+5000%22&s=stars&type=Repositories): 97 are in English. The other three are in Chinese.

Comment: Which is linked to the various other "what should we ask in the ${year} survey?" questions.